# ChromeDriverManager().install() is giving error while running through Jenkins

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, jenkins, python-behave

I am working on Python BDD with selenium, and I am using

```
self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    service=ChromeService(
        ChromeDriverManager().install()
    ),
    options=chrome_options
)
```

to launch the chrome browser.
This is working fine when it is running in local but when I try to run it through Jenkins I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 174, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 95, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 85, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
OSError: [Errno 101] Network is unreachable
```

I tried to change the proxy setting in Jenkins but still facing the problem.

Comment: Do you get the same problem when you run the python script from within the Jenkins machine/container (not using Jenkins)? If so, there might be something blocking the connection from the Jenkins host itself that is unrelated to Jenkins.

Comment: If I run it from terminal, then I have to do proxy setting then below step get succussed and get another error of network unreachable.  

 ""self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    service=ChromeService(
        ChromeDriverManager().install()
    ),
    options=chrome_options
)""


another error: 
    raise exception_class(value)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Network Error (dns_unresolved_hostname)

Your requested host "localhost" could not be resolved by DNS.

Comment: `Your requested host "localhost" could not be resolved by DNS.` is there anything running on localhost?

Comment: No, Only Jenkins is running.

Comment: I upgraded selenium, from 4.5 to 4.7.2 so now network error is gone but getting a different error of 

"selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed."

"selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed.
  (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
  (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)"

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50642913/3730626